# Pixels in Fedora 29 show up as “dead” but they are actually active

Tags: display, fedora, stuck-pixel

I get blocks of dead pixels on Fedora 29 (The same happened with 28). But they are not dead. When I go to the applications overview, or when I am logging in to the computer, the pixels work fine. But when I am focused on an application, they display black.

I can't click the black blocks either. The dead blocks come and go at random, and come in different sizes and places. The screen is likely not the issue here as it works fine otherwise.

The blue color on the screen is only *slightly* off. Highlighting color is normal for some applications, but darker for than usual for the rest.

Is this specific to my device, or just a Fedora thing? Does anyone know what this is or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community! That said, it made utterly no sense [to present your question as a 1, 2, 3 list with even a “Part 2” in your original version](https://superuser.com/revisions/1387163/1). Re-edited it to actually be clearer and readable. Past that, what you are describing sounds like a video card problem. Possibly a driver issue or a damaged video card.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try to look into that. Do you know how I can find and change drivers in Fedora, or even Linux in general for that matter? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What I posted is the most I know and can help with. Good luck dealing with this!